# JFrame wont appear when running program?

Tags: jframe

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.util.HashMap;



   // Java program to create a simple calculator
   // with basic +, -, /, * using java swing elements


   public class calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        // create a frame
        static JFrame f;

        // create a textfield
      static JTextField weeksField = new JTextField("#");
      static JTextField hoursField = new JTextField("#");
      static JTextField rateField = new JTextField("$/hr");
      static JTextField diffField = new JTextField("%");
      static JTextField mpgField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField distanceField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField gaspriceField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField insuranceField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField toolsField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField miscField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField workerhrField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField workersField = new JTextField();
      static JTextField workercostField = new JTextField();

      static JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Advanced Quote Calculator");
      static JLabel weeksLabel = new JLabel("Expected Weeks:");
      static JLabel hoursLabel = new JLabel("Expected Hours:");
      static JLabel rateLabel = new JLabel("Hourly Rate:");
      static JLabel diffLabel = new JLabel("Diff. Adjustment:");
      static JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel("Gross Total:");
      static JLabel taxLabel = new JLabel("Tax @ 30%:");
      static JLabel nettotalLabel = new JLabel("Net Total:");
      static JLabel distLabel = new JLabel("Distance:");
      static JLabel mpgLabel = new JLabel("Avg MPG:");
      static JLabel gaspriceLabel = new JLabel("Gas Price:");
      static JLabel insurLabel = new JLabel("Insurance Monthly:");
      static JLabel toolLabel = new JLabel("Tools & Equipment:");
      static JLabel worknumLabel = new JLabel("Number of Workers:");
      static JLabel workhourLabel = new JLabel("Predicted Hours");
      static JLabel workercostLabel = new JLabel("Worker Hourly Rate:");
      static JLabel misexpLabel = new JLabel("Misc. Expenses:");
      static JLabel gascostLabel = new JLabel("Gas Cost:");
      static JLabel insurcostLabel = new JLabel("Insurance Cost:");
      static JLabel workertotalLabel = new JLabel("Worker Cost:");
      static JLabel comprofitLabel = new JLabel("Company Profit:");
      static JLabel perprofitLabel = new JLabel("Personal Profit");
      static JLabel weekpprofitLabel = new JLabel("Weekly Personal Profit:");
      static JLabel weekcprofitLabel = new JLabel("Weekly Company Profit:");
      static JLabel tooltotalLabel = new JLabel("Tools and Equipment:");
      static JLabel misctotalLabel = new JLabel("Misc Exp Total:");

        // store operator and operands
        String s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12;

        // default constructor
        calculator()
        {
            s0 = s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = s5 = s6 = s7 = s8 = s9 = s10 = s11 = s12 = "";
        }

        // main function
        public void main(String args[])
        {
            // create a frame
            f = new JFrame("calculator");

            try {
                // set look and feel
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            // create a object of class
            calculator c = new calculator();

            // create a textfield
            weeksField = new JTextField("#");
            hoursField = new JTextField("#");
            rateField = new JTextField("$/hr");
            diffField = new JTextField("%");
            mpgField = new JTextField("#");
            distanceField = new JTextField("#");
            gaspriceField = new JTextField("$");
            insuranceField = new JTextField("$");
            toolsField = new JTextField("$");
            miscField = new JTextField("$");
            workerhrField = new JTextField("#");
            workersField = new JTextField("#");
            workercostField = new JTextField("$");

            titleLabel = new JLabel("Advanced Quote Calculator");
            weeksLabel = new JLabel("Expected Weeks:");
            hoursLabel = new JLabel("Expected Hours:");
            rateLabel = new JLabel("Hourly Rate:");
            diffLabel = new JLabel("Diff. Adjustment:");
            totalLabel = new JLabel("Gross Total:");
            taxLabel = new JLabel("Tax @ 30%:");
            nettotalLabel = new JLabel("Net Total:");
            distLabel = new JLabel("Distance:");
            mpgLabel = new JLabel("Avg MPG:");
            gaspriceLabel = new JLabel("Gas Price:");
            insurLabel = new JLabel("Insurance Monthly:");
            toolLabel = new JLabel("Tools & Equipment:");
            worknumLabel = new JLabel("Number of Workers:");
            workhourLabel = new JLabel("Predicted Hours");
            workercostLabel = new JLabel("Worker Hourly Rate:");
            misexpLabel = new JLabel("Misc. Expenses:");
            gascostLabel = new JLabel("Gas Cost:");
            insurcostLabel = new JLabel("Insurance Cost:");
            workertotalLabel = new JLabel("Worker Cost:");
            comprofitLabel = new JLabel("Company Profit:");
            perprofitLabel = new JLabel("Personal Profit");
            weekpprofitLabel = new JLabel("Weekly Personal Profit:");
            weekcprofitLabel = new JLabel("Weekly Company Profit:");
            tooltotalLabel = new JLabel("Tools and Equipment:");
            misctotalLabel = new JLabel("Misc Exp Total:");


            // set the textfield to non editable
            weeksField.setEditable(false);
            hoursField.setEditable(false);
            rateField.setEditable(false);
            diffField.setEditable(false);
            mpgField.setEditable(false);
            distanceField.setEditable(false);
            gaspriceField.setEditable(false);
            insuranceField.setEditable(false);
            toolsField.setEditable(false);
            miscField.setEditable(false);
            workerhrField.setEditable(false);
            workersField.setEditable(false);
            workercostField.setEditable(false);


            // create number buttons and some operators
            JButton b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;

            // create number buttons
            b0 = new JButton("Calculate");
            b1 = new JButton("Clear");

            // create a panel
            JPanel frame = new JPanel();

            b1.addActionListener(c);
            b0.addActionListener(c);


            // add elements to panel
            frame.add(titleLabel);
            frame.add(weeksLabel);
            frame.add(hoursLabel);
            frame.add(rateLabel);
            frame.add(diffLabel);
            frame.add(totalLabel);
            frame.add(taxLabel);
            frame.add(nettotalLabel);
            frame.add(distLabel);
            frame.add(mpgLabel);
            frame.add(gaspriceLabel);
            frame.add(insurLabel);
            frame.add(toolLabel);
            frame.add(workercostLabel);
            frame.add(workhourLabel);
            frame.add(worknumLabel);
            frame.add(misexpLabel);
            frame.add(tooltotalLabel);
            frame.add(weeksField);
            frame.add(hoursField);
            frame.add(rateField);
            frame.add(diffField);

            titleLabel.setBounds(190, 15, 500, 25);
            weeksLabel.setBounds(30, 80, 150, 15);
            hoursLabel.setBounds(30, 110, 150, 15);
            rateLabel.setBounds(30, 140, 150, 15);
            diffLabel.setBounds(30, 170, 150, 15);
            distLabel.setBounds(30, 200, 150, 15);
            mpgLabel.setBounds(30, 230, 150, 15);
            gaspriceLabel.setBounds(30, 260, 150, 15);
            worknumLabel.setBounds(30, 290, 150, 15);
            workercostLabel.setBounds(30, 320, 150, 15);
            workhourLabel.setBounds(30, 350, 150, 15);
            insurLabel.setBounds(30, 380, 150, 15);
            toolLabel.setBounds(30, 410, 150, 15);
            misexpLabel.setBounds(30, 440, 150, 15);
            totalLabel.setBounds(400, 80, 200, 15);
            taxLabel.setBounds(400, 110, 200, 15);
            gascostLabel.setBounds(400, 140, 200, 15);
            workertotalLabel.setBounds(400, 170, 200, 15);
            insurcostLabel.setBounds(400, 200, 200, 15);
            tooltotalLabel.setBounds(400, 230, 200, 15);
            nettotalLabel.setBounds(400, 260, 200, 15);
            comprofitLabel.setBounds(400, 490, 200, 15);
            perprofitLabel.setBounds(400, 520, 200, 15);
            weeksField.setBounds(180, 80, 100, 20);
            hoursField.setBounds(180, 110, 100, 20);
            rateField.setBounds(180, 140, 100, 20);
            diffField.setBounds(180, 170, 100, 20);


            // set Background of panel
            frame.setBackground(Color.blue);

            // add panel to frame
            f.add(frame);

            f.setSize(750, 750);
            f.show();
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }


   }`
```

I cant figure out how to get my Jframe to open nothing happens when i execute the code?  Ive tried doing all my jframe work in the main class but it didnt work.  Ive looked for answers on other post and im pretty new to this so any help is great!                       ....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).